# PlayOnLinux is unable to find 32 bits OpenGL libraries. (18.04)

Tags: wine, playonlinux

```
PlayOnLinux is unable to find 32 bits OpenGL libraries.
You might encounter problems with your games
```

I get the above message when trying to run PlayOnLinux. I'm not sure what I did to cause this issue. I use PlayOnLinux for WinRar. Most of the posts I've seen on this problem seem unrelated to my specific issue or seem to only semi-fix the problem.

After getting the above message I get:

```
PlayOnLinux cannot find wine (from Wine)
You should install it to use PlayOnLinux
```

Then when I run WinRar, I get:

```
PlayOnLinux has encountered an error. If the program does not work
correctly, it might be the cause of the problem.
Visit www.playonlinux.com to get further information
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.
Thanks.

OK, I tried installing wine-stable using this:

```
sudo apt-get update
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key && sudo apt-key add Release.key
sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

I got the message that I had unmet dependencies in the form of wine-stable. so I ran this:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends wine-stable
```

I got the message:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-stable : Depends: wine-stable-amd64 (= 4.0~bionic) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: wine-stable-i386 (= 4.0~bionic)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Somehow Wine seems to be broken on my system.

Comment: If you haven't already you should install wine-stable and wine32 from the ubuntu repositories and try again.

Comment: @kc1di I tried the above suggestions, but ran into problems as per my edited post. Any suggestions?

Comment: Again forget trying to install via winehq and go to a terminal and install wine-stable and wiine32 from the repository first.  Then install playonlinux and you can install which ever version of wine you want from there.

Comment: @kc1di How do I install via the Ubuntu repository? What command do I run specifically? I've tried: sudo apt-get install wine-stable and sudo apt-get install wine32 and I get the same unmet dependency errors as above...

Comment: which version of ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Clean out any winehq ppa's you've added the do sudo apt update and try installing wine-stable and wine32 again. you may have to uninstall any wine packages you've already installed also.

Comment: I'm also having this issue, with both the 32bit and 64bit opengl libraries (when I start playonlinux, it pops up first the error mentioned in the question, then the same error again but with "64" in place of "32"). I'm running linux mint, and have installed winehq-stable from aptitude, and playonlinux via the .deb from the playonlinux website (because when I did playonlinux from aptitude, it was out of date, which caused other problems, so removed it and got the current from the website).